# Same script performing differently in different locations with same data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently having very strange results from a script designed to take a snapshot of a database in one sheet, and store that data at the time of running the script in another sheet to keep a record.

It has previously worked, however now after running the script nothing appears to happen. In an attempt to find a solution, I have tested the script on a designated test file and on the main Google Sheets but pointed towards duplicate sheets, but each performs very differently, so I am struggling to understand what is causing the issue. Let me explain:

1) Script pointed to the 'main' sheets. This used to work, but now the snapData script doesn't make a record. This is the code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var current = ss.getSheetByName('Fees (management)');
var database = ss.getSheetByName('Fees (data)');

var current_rows = current.getLastRow();
var database_rows = database.getLastRow() + 1;
var database_rows_new = current_rows + database_rows - 2;
var rows_new = current.getRange("A2:F" + current_rows).getValues();

database.getRange("A" + database_rows + ":F" + database_rows_new).setValues(rows_new);

}
```

To summarise, data is A2:F from sheet 'Fees (data)' should be stored on the sheet 'Fees (management)'. When the script is run, nothing happens to either sheet.

2) I duplicated 'Fees (data)' and 'Fees (management)' and called them 'Data' and 'Management'. I then created a snapData2 script (copy and pasted the script) and pointed this new script to the duplicated sheets. I'll copy the code below to make it clear.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var current = ss.getSheetByName('Management');
var database = ss.getSheetByName('Data');

var current_rows = current.getLastRow();
var database_rows = database.getLastRow() + 1;
var database_rows_new = current_rows + database_rows - 2;
var rows_new = current.getRange("A2:F" + current_rows).getValues();

database.getRange("A" + database_rows + ":F" + database_rows_new).setValues(rows_new);

}
```

However, the script generates the error `TypeError: Cannot call method "getLastRow" of null. (line 7, file "snapData2")`

The duplicated sheets have identical data formatted in the same way, so I am not sure why snapData2 generates this error, but snapData does not.

3) I have created a sandbox test file with tabs 'Fees (data)' and 'Fees (management)' with data copied like number 1 above and copied the snapData script to run on the test file. Again, to be clear on this script, I have copied below:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var current = ss.getSheetByName('Fees (management)');
var database = ss.getSheetByName('Fees (data)');

var current_rows = current.getLastRow();
var database_rows = database.getLastRow() + 1;
var database_rows_new = current_rows + database_rows - 2;
var rows_new = current.getRange("A2:F" + current_rows).getValues();

database.getRange("A" + database_rows + ":F" + database_rows_new).setValues(rows_new);

}
```

But in the test file, this script works exactly as intended.

I can provide a link to the test file, but unfortunately the real file contains sensitive information, so cannot make this public: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-qMstcIIDFffEAAFLHg3ZISdqLYLc2IegP-d6T9Q1jA/edit?usp=sharing

I cannot understand why the exact same script pointing to duplicated information can perform in such different ways.

What I want to achieve is number 1 above performing like number 3. Any help that can be provided is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function func1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var current=ss.getSheetByName('Fees (management)');
  var database=ss.getSheetByName('Fees (data)');  
  var rows_new=current.getRange(2,1,current.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  database.getRange(database.getLastRow()+1,1,rows_new.length,rows_new[0].length).setValues(rows_new);
}
```

View Executions:

[image]

I'm guessing that the problem might be that you have formula's in your targetsheet which are making it difficult for the script to determine what the last row is and you may actualy be copy data to the very end of your spreadsheet which is far below where you expect.  So here is a version to test that hypothesis.  In this version you will be prompted to provide the target row.

```
function testfunc1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var current=ss.getSheetByName('Fees (management)');
  var database=ss.getSheetByName('Fees (data)'); 
  var rows_new=current.getRange(2,1,current.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Target Row", "Enter Row Number of Target", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    database.getRange(parseInt(resp.getResponseText()),1,rows_new.length,rows_new[0].length).setValues(rows_new);
  }
}
```

Comment: No. There isn't an error, it just doesn't place the information from Fees (management) to Fees (data). I might try running this data off the main file for now and use IMPORTRANGE to bring this back to the main sheet once the script has been run on the secondary file.

Comment: Is this the screen you mean? https://ibb.co/y6X0xJ2 The 18.26% error rate shown relates to other scripts that I'm aware are running in error on purpose.

Comment: I put the image in my answer.

Comment: https://ibb.co/bJ4xCLY It says 'Completed' but there is still no data appearing on Fees (management) as expected. This same thing happens for your Func1 script and the same for my snapData script

Comment: I provided a test function with some explanation please read and try.